# How to connect firebase database with react js Todo App in ES6

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

in react js with ES6 how to link my Compnents with firebase database

Comment: Are you using Redux?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reactfire](https://github.com/firebase/reactfire). See the quickstart guide [here](https://github.com/firebase/reactfire/blob/master/docs/quickstart.md).

Also, see the following Rally Coding video, by Stephen Grider, on precisely this topic: [Combining Redux and Firebase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UHJq5NOtNG4). He explains how to use Redux with Firebase without using reactfire, as an alternative setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can use re-base - https://github.com/tylermcginnis/re-base (the easy way) 

or 

(the hard way) bind each item in the component's state to the snapshot.val() as per https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

I first started with re-base and at the moment trying to figure how to do it without it.